# Drawing on the canvas with a constant component in Delphi

Tags: delphi, canvas, delphi-xe

Is there a way to draw in a canvas with a layout. I mean that I have an object that moves and constant axis. Everybody knows when the object moves from point A to point B we should fill the rectangle by some color. One attentive user may notice that image blinks.

One way: If I have a constant canvas with a set of objects like axis, grids etc... and another one with the moving objects.
 I can combine them like

```delphi
SumCanvas.Pixels[i, j] = ConstCanvas.Pixels[i, j] + MovingCanvas.Pixels[i, j]
```

filling only the `MovingCanvas`.
Maybe there is another way?

**UPD**

A piece of code:
Self is inherited from.

```
// ...
Canvas.Rectangle(-1, -1, Self.Width, Self.Height);
// Fill all area of canvas by
// clWhite. This is a reason of an image blinking.

// ...
Shape.position := position; // the coordinate of permanently moving object;
// ...
{The constant part}
AddGrid; // drawing a constantCanvas (axis and grids);
for Shape in FListOfShapes do // TListOfShapes = TList<IShape>
  shape.draw; // a set of another shape with constant coordinates.
// ...
```

Comment: Draw everything on a **hidden** canvas (TBitmap.Canvas) and after that draw that (Bitmap) on the real canvas

Comment: @SirRufo, what is a profit of this a *hidden* canvas? Doesn`t the real canvas blink in an assignation?

Comment: @user2957581, he's talking about the double buffer effect, the image is first drawn on-to an off canvas bitmap and then drawn on the Canvas.

Comment: You often don't need double buffering because the compositor does that for you. Very hard for us to comment on your code that we cannot see.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, always better to have internal buffering that you can control instead of default.

Comment: @peter Not always. Needless buffering costs.

Comment: Fix your problem by painting the background at the right time.

Comment: You should determine what is "blinking". What exactly does blink, what is happening during the blinking. When I drew a map in my app, I had a dedicated background TBitmap that only was re-rendered if the window was resized, or map was scrolled, or map was zoomed. So when I had to refresh the map, I just bit-blitted it to the on-screen canvas (In some apps that was a TPaintBox, in others that was TImage). Then I just drawn one figure after another. Also do not copy anything like `SumCanvas.Pixels[i, j]` - accessing pixels is a really terribly slow way. Copy all the canvas at once,not its pixels